# how to handle scrolling of scrollview with uitextview as its child and have implemented autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am having a trouble when i add uitextview inside uiscrollview. UITextview is having toolbar added with keyboard. When i start editing, contents are hide behind uitoolbar. and as we all know that when we implement UI with autolayout, it provides scrolling facility with uiscrollview automatically. we do not require to set contentoffset.

Comment: you need to update constraints(Height) of scrollview when keyboard(toolbar appears).

Comment: or alternately, you could alter the size of the view and leave the constraints be (so long as they work with the altered view)